# Move through a list by an int

Tags: python

I have two lists: D_Roll, and Space, as such:

```
D_Roll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Space = list(range(1,37))
```

What I want is to take the value of a random D_Roll, i.e.

```
x = random.choice(D_Roll)
```

and add it to the current index of the Space list.

So: D_Roll produces 9, I want Space to move to index 8.

I thought I could do something like:

```
Current_Space = {Space : Space + x in Space}
```

But it won't allow int's.

How can I move along the index of a list?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Space to move to index 8'?

Comment: What is the expected value of `Space` when D_Roll  produces 9?

Comment: Space is a list 1-36, starting at index[0] = 1 index[37] = 36.

I want the value of D_Roll to move through the list Space, by whatever is rolled.

Comment: You are not clear. Can you output the value of `space` after `D_Roll`  gives value 9??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access the index directly.

```
Current_Space = Space[random.choice(D_Roll) - 1]  # minus one cuz 0-index
```

Comment: How did you even understand what is being asked? ;-)

Comment: Hehe. Following line gave me a hint. So: D_Roll produces 9, I want Space to move to index 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of the item in the list which appears at 'x' then try

```
import random

D_Roll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Space = list(range(1,37))

x = random.choice(D_Roll)

Current_Space = Space[x-1]

#check the output
print(x)
print(Current_Space)
```

If you want to start with a value for `space` and then move to a new random value then try

```
import random

Original_Space = 5 #set to what you want

D_Roll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Space = list(range(1,37))

x = random.choice(D_Roll)

Current_Space = Space[(Original_Space +x -1)]

#check input and output
print(Original_Space)
print(x)
print(Current_Space)
```

Note: this code could put your new value outside your range for `space`. You can add an `if` statement to check for this and start at the beginning of the list